# How to power on external USB hard drive

Tags: usb, hard-drive, power-management

I have an external USB hard drive on my Ubuntu 18.04. I am remotely managing the system with Teamviewer (I have ssh access as well). I want to remotely power down my hard drive and then power it on again when I need it.
I powered it down using the button in "Disks". However this way it disappears and I can't find a way to power it back on.
I tried running `udevadm trigger` but it didn't come up. Only way I've found to power it up again is by rebooting.
So is there a way to power it back on remotely?